# cifs/smb client library in C/C++

Tags: windows, smb, cifs

i'm looking for a C/C++ cifs/smb client library that can be used in a close source commercial product, it should have apis like openfile, readfile, writefile, listdir, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the YNQ SMB library.